# Java: Is PrintWriter providing some form of "clue" about the request-origin platform's preferred line endings?

Tags: java, tcp, newline, printwriter, line-endings

This is about `java.io.PrintWriter` from Oracle JDK 8

I've written a small test to make sure some TCP-interfacing service (we don't own this service!) always returns CRLF and nothing else.
However, I notice that tests which are expected to fail (containing only LF) are passing... 
When debugging the test, I see that the response is fine (only CRLF) - but we have a user that's complaining that he's still receiving the response with LF!

My thought currently is that: since I am using `printWriter.println(query);`, perhaps `println()` from the `PrintWriter` class (especially the `ln` part!) is providing my current CRLF (I am running the tests from a Win10 machine) and the server is trying to be nice and is therefore adapting the line endings according to clues received from the source.

- I will commission a linux test box and I will write a simple application to confirm my conjecture above. However, even if I manage to find some correlation (I will update here), I would still like to confirm, with someone who knows the `PrintWriter` class, that this is indeed the location where things get "customized" and cause the server to switch line ending composition... 
  For example: Perhaps it's not `PrintWriter`, but the TcpIpService of the machine that is providing this clue? And therefore, my correlation here does not point to the cause of different responses (I.E.: It's not Java, it's the OS)

Update: Before trying it in linux, I tried changing the println into print but then the `buffReader.read()` (a java.io.BufferedReader method) gets "stuck".
I tried also swapping println() for write() and flush() - read() is stuck again.

How should I refactor the println() method I am using, to have control over the line endings provided? I would like to be able to simulate CRLF, CR and LF.

Update: I am including a small program to reproduce the part that I am interested in. Unfortunately, I am still quite far from obtaining a linux machine to see if the output from this program changes under linux:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class NewWhoisClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int portNumber = 43;
        String whoisHostName = "213.248.242.76";
        String query = "nic.beer";

        Socket whoisSocket;
        PrintWriter printWriter;
        BufferedReader buffReader;
        try {
            whoisSocket = new Socket(whoisHostName, portNumber);
            buffReader = new BufferedReader( 
                new InputStreamReader(whoisSocket.getInputStream())
            );
            printWriter = 
            new PrintWriter(whoisSocket.getOutputStream(),true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new AssertionError("Socket setup failed", e);
        }

        try {
            printWriter.println(query);
            StringBuilder responseWIP = new StringBuilder();

            int value;
            while ((value = buffReader.read()) != -1) {
                responseWIP.append((char) value);
            }
            String result = responseWIP.toString();

            ///
            if (result.contains("\r\n")) {
                System.out.println("Result contained CRLF");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Some other line ending or no CRLF at all");
            }
            ///
        
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AssertionError("Socket communication failed", e);
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Well, the [documentation for `println`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println--) is rather clear: "The line separator string is defined by the system property line.separator, and is not necessarily a single newline character ('\n')."

Comment: I would avoid using `PrintWriter` completely. It's a Java 1.1 class, and makes a lot of assumptions about line endings, not to mention encoding.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yes, I am sorry I didn't read the doc, I usually don't find what I need there... In this case it's pretty clear. Could you please consider my case (I provided some update in the question)? I don't need println() with implied, system-specific line.separator, I need to be able to control that LS... I wasn't able to get read() working with my attempts to do that, so far

Comment: @Kayaman Interesting! what would you recommend?

Comment: @DraxDomax to be frank it's not very clear to me what you're doing and what your purpose is. It would help if you could [edit] your question to provide some code.

Comment: Well if you're only writing `CRLF`, then a simple `OutputStreamWriter` would suffice.

Comment: @Kayaman Thanks. I do however want to parameterize the line separator used. One test would send CRLF (simulating a windows user), one test LF (linux), one test CR (mac). Would OutputStreamWriter expose the line endings for me to somehow choose the one I need?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I uploaded some code which will work on its own. I am not sure how to further explain my needs (sorry!). Basically, I see I am getting different line endings from the server and I want to know if it's because of the printWriter.println(query); (like, the client detects Win in println and sends CRLF, and then the server detects CRLF and responds CRLF). Ideally, I would like to have control on the line endings I am sending (especially if this determined the server response format)

Comment: If you're *sending* stuff with CRLF what you *receive* depends on the server, not on you. But yeah, looks like the server is responding in kind :)

Comment: "looks like the server is responding in kind" - are you saying you ran this code under a different OS and were able to see differences in debug? :) (I realise what a slim chance there is to see a "yes")

Comment: @DraxDomax no I didn't. But now I did, and even on linux I'm getting "Result contained CRLF". I did another test by explicitly printing `\n` instead of using `println` (so `printWriter.print(query + "\n");`), same result. BUT I tried with telnet on linux and I'm not getting CRLF, just LF. Also verified what java thinks is the system's line separator and it says it is "\n". At this point I have no idea why the server is responding with CRLF when the request is done via java.